# Showing ListView in nested Columns

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, flutter-layout

I'm trying to use a scrollable ListView in my app but I'm having some difficulties. I set out my structure of the IU using nested Columns and Rows and I want to show this ListView a few Columns deep on the bottom half of the screen. I've figured out that if you use a ListView in a Column you need to wrap it in an expended widget and if that Column's inside another Column that also need to be wrapped in an Expanded widget

```
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Container(
          child: Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
            child:
                ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[500],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
          ),
        ]))
      ])))
    ]));
  }
```

however if I try to add any properties to the nested container it will give me this error repeatedly

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderColoredBox#bcf8d relayoutBoundary=up1
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

```
    return Container(
        child: Column(children: [
      Container(
          **color: Colors.white,**
          **padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),**
          child: Expanded(
              child: Column(children: [
        Expanded(
            child:
                ListView(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8), children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[600],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            color: Colors.amber[500],
            child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
          ),
        ]))
      ])))
    ]));
  }
```

Can someone tell me why? even if I'm just changing the colour is errors out. Perhaps there is another widget I should be using? I need to be able to style the containers and it doesn't look like I can to this if I want to use ListView.

Actual code below:

```
class _ThisViewState extends State<ThisView> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Title',
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text("Title"),
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Styles.primaryGreen),
          body: Container(
              color: Styles.backgroundColorLight,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  customCard1(),
                  customCard2(),
                ],
              ))),
    );
  }

  Widget customCard2() {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        color: Colors.white,
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, top: 28, bottom: 14),
            child: Text(
              "Subtitle",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: Styles.textSizeSubheading,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          InfoContainer()
        ]));
  }

}

class _infoContainerState extends State<infoContainer> {


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24, bottom: 8),
          child: Text(
            DateFormat('EEEE, d MMMM y').format(DateTime.now()),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: Styles.textSizeDefault,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.amber[600],
              child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.amber[500],
              child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 50,
              color: Colors.amber[100],
              child: const Center(child: Text('Entry C')),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKVIe.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gS5n.png)

[when ListView is shrinkwrapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FVQa.png)

Comment: I am not really sure what you try to accomplish and why you have that many nested Columns. Could you maybe add a really simple sketch of the layout that you want? Also, having `Expanded` inside a `Container` does not make any sense, you probably want to lift the `Expanded` to be a direct child of the `Column`

Comment: ok sure I though using examples might be a bit easier but I can share my actual code :)

Comment: where is the `CustomCard1`

Comment: can you try giving the height to the listview. If it is possible for your view... It will make the view visible XD

Comment: I didn't include it in the code snippet cause I didn't think it was relevant and it takes up alot of space

Comment: I'm going to be loading the list view dynamically from the DB so it might be 1 item, it might be 20, So I don't think I can give it a definite height

Comment: if I set shrinkwrap to true I can see the listView but it doesnt scroll and gives me an overflow error when it gets too big for the page

Answer (score 0):

Below code will create a layout where the the bottom half of the screen is the `ListView`. In order to have a larger portion of the screen be the `ListView`, you can change the `flex` property of the `Expanded` widget. (see [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html))

```
Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(color: Colors.green),
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: ListView(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.amber[600],
          child: const Center(child: Text('Entry A')),
        ),
        Container(
          height: 50,
          color: Colors.amber[500],
          child: const Center(child: Text('Entry B')),
        ),
      ],
    )),
  ],
);
```